# TestController is not a function got undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs

So I can't seem to get my controller to work when it is in a different file.

Right now I am just trying to do small test controller to see how angular works. Here are my files:

Here is my app.js

```
(function(angular) {
    var AngularApp = angular.module('AngularApp', []);
})(window.angular);
```

Here is my controller file: TestController.js

```
(function(angular) {
    var AngularApp = angular.module('AngularApp');

    AngularApp.controller("TestController", ["$scope", function($scope) {
        $scope.appTitle = "AngularApp";
    }]);
})(window.angular);
```

Here is my html:

```
<!doctype html>
<!--[if lt IE 7]>      <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7" lang=""> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8" lang=""> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9" lang=""> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!--> <html class="no-js" lang="" ng-app="AngularApp" ng-controller="TestController"> <!--<![endif]-->
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
        <title ng-bind="appTitle"></title>
        <meta name="description" content="">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="apple-touch-icon.png">

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/libs/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <style>
            body {
                padding-top: 50px;
                padding-bottom: 20px;
            }
        </style>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/libs/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/css/main.css">

        <script src="/assets/libs/modernizr-2.8.3-respond-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
        <script src="/assets/libs/angular/angular.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        ...
    </div> <!-- /container -->        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="/assets/libs/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"><\/script>')</script>

        <script src="/assets/libs/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

        <script src="/app/app.js"></script>
        <scirpt src="/app/components/home/TestController.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Right now I am just trying to replace the title of the page. I have tried numerous different ways of doing this. Right now I have the js wrapped in immediately invoked functions, but I have tried with out that. I have tried making the module a global variable and just using that variable to define a controller. Ex:

App.js:

```
AngularApp = angular.module('AngularApp', []);
```

TestController.js:

```
AngularApp.controller("TestController", ["$scope", function($scope) {
    $scope.appTitle = "AngularApp";
}]);
```

I have also tried the dependencies with and without the array notation.

The controller seems to work fine when it is in the same file but I can't get it to work when it is in a seperate file. I always get the following error:

[image]

I am using angular version 1.4.8

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: have you included it in your index.html? it would get included just like any other script `<script src="scripts/controllers/yourController.js"></script>`

Comment: Yeah, it is at the bottom of the file: <scirpt src="/app/components/home/TestController.js"></script>

Comment: You just helped me realize I spelled script wrong... Thank you!